# Hide Global Navigation when Printing in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, css

I am trying to hide the top navigation when printing.  I am currently using the following CSS to do so:

```
<style>
@media print
{#ms-breadcrumb-top{display:none !important;
    }
}
</style>
```

However, the above is still showing the top navigation when printing.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using on prem environment, you should be using this selector:

```
#DeltaTopNavigation { display: none; }
```

Currently you're using the selector to hide the ribbon, which is different from the navigation.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the below css as well :

```
<style type="text/css">  
  #s4-titlerow {    display:none;  

  } 
</style>
```

Source:

[Hide The Top Navigation On A SharePoint 2013 And Office 365 Site Using CSS](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/hide-the-top-navigation-on-a-sharepoint-2013-and-office-365-site-using-css)

**Or** try the below css :

```
<style type="text/css"> .ms-breadcrumb-top { display: none; } </style>
```

Comment: This worked.  Thank you.